# Restrict the number of object instantiations from a class to a given number

Tags: c++, object, instantiation

Given a class, I would like to limit the number of objects created from this class to a given number, say 4.

Is there a method to achieve this?

Comment: That depends. Do copies of instances count as new instances or are they fine?

Comment: You say object _creations_ rather than _instances_. If I create 4 instances, then delete one, should I be allowed to create another? You might want to think about thread safety, too. Notably, none of the answer below consider this (though it isn't a particularly complex extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea is to count the number of created instances in some static variable. I would implement it like this. Simpler approaches exist, but this one has some advantages.

```
template<class T, int maxInstances>
class Counter {
protected:
    Counter() {
        if( ++noInstances() > maxInstances ) {
            throw logic_error( "Cannot create another instance" );
        }
    }

    int& noInstances() {
        static int noInstances = 0;
        return noInstances;
    }

    /* this can be uncommented to restrict the number of instances at given moment rather than creations
    ~Counter() {
        --noInstances();
    }
    */
};

class YourClass : Counter<YourClass, 4> {
}
```

Comment: As long as you're defining a template superclass, you might as well add a second template parameter for the max number of instances.  I.e.: `template<class T, int MAX_INSTANCES> class Counter {...};`

Comment: +1. But better to wrap the static member into an inline accessor function, to avoid the template definition in the source file.

Comment: @EdwardLoper, it was kind of a compliment to Luchian Grigore's answer, where he preserves that constant from the question, found it funny, will edit, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the **instance manager pattern**. Basically what you do is restrict instantiations of that class to a manager class.

```
class A
{
private: //redundant
   friend class AManager;
   A();
};

class AManager
{
   static int noInstances; //initialize to 0
public:
   A* createA()
   {
      if ( noInstances < 4 )
      {
         ++noInstances;
         return new A;
      }
      return NULL; //or throw exception
   }
};
```

A shorter way is throwing an exception from the constructor, but that can be hard to get right:

```
class A
{
public:
   A()
   {
       static int count = 0;
       ++count;
       if ( count >= 4 )
       {
           throw TooManyInstances();
       }
   }
};
```

Comment: What's hard about the constructor solution, except for the fact it's horribly thread unsafe, like the other solution?

Comment: @rubenvb hard to get right :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810839/throwing-exceptions-from-constructors

Comment: ok, not seeing much relevance in the linked question. Care to explain?

Comment: @rubenvb not much to explain. :) I just find it non-trivial. If it's easy for you, kudos. :)

Comment: Properly throwing an exception from the constructor is easier if you encapsulate the counter into a CRTP base class.