# Is such assignment a good idea in C++

Tags: c++, new-operator, variable-assignment, placement-new

A lot of classes has assignment operator (operator=) the same code as in destructor and than very similar code of copy constructor.

So is it good idea to implement the assignment in such way?

```
Point& operator=(const Point& point)
{
    if(&point != this)
    {
        //Call the destructor
        this->~Point();

        //Make the placement new
        //Assignment is made because some compilers optimise such code as just
        //  new Point;
        Point* p_n = new (this) Point(point);

        //We where placing in this place so pointers should be equal
        assert(p_n == this);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: If you do this, be sure to check `&point != this` first!

Comment: Also, this code is not exception safe - in case of exception in `new (this) Point(point)` there will be double destruction. Just use [copy and swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) idiom.

Comment: can the placement new raise exceptions?

Comment: @Seagull, Point's ctor (or the type being constructed) can throw.

Comment: @Seagull, it is not placement new, it is `Point` constructor.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk I was convienced that throwing from constructor is a terrible thing so it should be avoided.

Comment: @Seagull, "I was convienced that throwing from constructor is a terrible thing" - throwing from **constructor** is wonderful thing! It allows to enstablish object invariants and [use it easily](http://stackoverflow.com/a/810850/1762344).

Comment: @Seagull Maybe you are thinking of throwing from a destructor. Now that is a terrible thing.

Comment: is possible using placement new like that.. but hell that's a pain O_O. placement new is more usefull in other contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Herb Sutter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1661064/herb-sutter) has addressed this in [one of his GotW articles](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/023.htm).  I recommend that you read it. His conclusion:

> The original idiom is full of pitfalls, it's often wrong, and it makes
>   life a living hell for the authors of derived classes. I'm sometimes
>   tempted to post the above code in the office kitchen with the caption:
>   "Here be dragons."
>
> From the GotW coding standards:
>
> - prefer writing a common private function to share code between copying and copy assignment, if necessary; never use the trick of
>     implementing copy assignment in terms of copy construction by using an
>     explicit destructor followed by placement new, even though this trick
>     crops up every three months on the newsgroups (i.e., never write:
>
>   ```
>   T& T::operator=( const T& other )
>   {
>       if( this != &other)
>       {
>           this->~T();             // evil
>           new (this) T( other );  // evil
>       }
>       return *this;
>   }
>   ```

Answer (score 6):

No. This is a bad idea, even though the C++ Standard uses this kind of thing as an example in a discussion of object lifetime. For a value type like `Point` it's not so bad, but if you derive from this class, this assignment implementation will change the type of the object from your derived type to `Point`; if there are virtual functions involved, you'll see a dramatic change in behavior.

Comment: In such case both assignment and copy constructors should be forbidden. My approach uses the copy constructor if it exists. Maybe I have not understood you.

Comment: @Seagull - I thought your point was to implement the assignment operator. Implementing it this way sets a trap for users of such a class, and the result is deadly. Try it!