# Is it safe to use placement new on 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, raii, placement-new, explicit-destructor-call

### Current Implementation

I have a class containing `unique_ptr` fields which depend on one other:

```
class ResourceManager {
  ResourceManager() {}

  ResourceManager(A* a_ptr) :
    b_ptr(new B(a)),
    c_ptr(new C(b_ptr.get())) {}

  ResourceManager& operator=(ResourceManager&& that) {
    // Call destructor, then construct a new instance on top
    ~ResourceManager();
    ResourceManager* new_this = new(this) ResourceManager();

    // Surely this must be the case, right?
    // Is there any reason to prefer using either?
    assert(new_this == this);

    new_this->b_ptr = that.b_ptr;
    new_this->c_ptr = that.c_ptr;

    return *new_this;
  }

  unique_ptr<B> b;
  unique_ptr<C> c;
};
```

### Use case

The use case here is that I would like to reassign new values to the pointers, whilst keeping the `ResourceManager` as a stack-allocated variable, or as a non-pointer class member.

With my current setup I imagine using it something like this:

```
A a, another_a;
ResourceManager r(&a);

// Use r...

// Destroy old ResourceManager and create the new one in place.
r = ResourceManager(&another_a);
```

The reason this is even a problem is due to the fact that B and C are non-assignable (for e.g. file streams)

### Ugly Alternative

An alternative uglier (and dangerous) method would be to explicitly `reset` the `unique_ptr` fields **crucially in reverse order** (remember that C depends on B, and hence must be destructed first), effectively mimicking the default destruction behaviour.

```
ResourceManager& operator=(ResourceManager&& that) {
  // Mimic destructor call (reverse-order destruction)
  c_ptr.reset();
  b_ptr.reset();

  b_ptr = that.b_ptr;
  c_ptr = that.c_ptr;

  return *this;    
}
```

Note that a **wrong** implementation would be to simply use the default assignment operator for `ResourceManager`. This will assign the field *in-order* which implies in-order destruction of the `unique_ptr`s, whereas we require reverse-order destruction.

### Questions

Is this usage of `this` pointer with placement `new` and the explicit destructor call safe?

Must I use the returned `new_this` pointer as opposed to the original `this` pointer (for example, if the `this` pointer technically becomes invalidated after calling the destructor)?

Are there any better suggested ways to achieve this? If add more such `unique_ptr` fields to the class, I would have to make sure that I add a copy to the assignment operator. For instance, is it possible to call the move constructor instead, like so:

```
ResourceManager& operator=(ResourceManager&& that) {
  // Call destructor
  ~ResourceManager();

  // Move-construct a new instance on top
  ResourceManager* new_this = new(this) ResourceManager(that);
  return *new_this;
}
```

Comment: Typically, the simplest way to implement an assignment operator is the *copy-and-swap* technique; or its *move-and-swap* equivalent: Take `ResourceManager` by value and then swap this parameter with `*this`.

Comment: Why is `C` depending on an instance of `B` that it does not own ? This is a recipe for failure and difficulties. If you could solve this root issue, then you would not have to worry about the defaulted assignment operator doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Note: the usage of placement `new` in the assignment operator (in general) was already [dealt with on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932333/is-such-assignment-a-good-idea-in-c). In general, it's a very bad idea. Most notably, your class should be marked `final` else it's incorrect. As [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/023.htm) put it so succinctly: *Here Be Dragons*.

Comment: @MatthieuM. `B` and `C` form various "chains" of filestream wrappers (e.g. `ZipInputStream`, etc.). They indeed ought to be taking ownership of the pointers.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That is a very good point with deriving classes, though I did not intend this class to be derivable anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution seems overly complex.

I would code it like this:

```
class ResourceManager {
  ResourceManager() {}

  ResourceManager(A* a_ptr) :
    b_ptr(new B(a)),
    c_ptr(new C(b_ptr.get())) {}

  ResourceManager& operator=(ResourceManager&& that) 
  {
    // the order of these moves/assignments is important
    // The old value of *(this->c_ptr) will be destroyed before
    // the old value of *(this->b_ptr) which is good because *c_ptr presumably
    // has an unprotected pointer to *b_ptr.
    c_ptr = std::move(that.c_ptr);
    b_ptr = std::move(that.b_ptr);
    //  (a better solution might be to use shared_ptr<B> rather than unique_ptr<B> 
    return *this;
  }

  unique_ptr<B> b_ptr;
  unique_ptr<C> c_ptr;
};
```

Note:  When the move assignment returns, `that` will "empty" meaning both `that.b_ptr` and `that.c_ptr` are `nullptr`.   This is the expected result of a move assignment.

Or if "reconstructing" the target of the assignment is important (assuming there's extra code not shown in this example that makes it so) I might add a move constructor and a swap method like so:

```
 ResourceManager(ResourceManager&& that)
 : b_ptr(std::move(that.b_ptr)),
   c_ptr(std::move(that.c_ptr))    
 {
 }

 void swap(ResourceManager & that)
 {
   b_ptr.swap(that.b_ptr);
   c_ptr.swap(that.c_ptr);  
 }

 ResourceManager& operator=(ResourceManager&& that) 
 {
     ResourceManager temp(std::move(that));
     this->swap(temp);
     return *this;
 }
```

Comment: Aha! And when 'that' gets destructud, it will do the right thing and delete the old pointers in order.

Comment: @WaelJ Only of you use swap instead of assign.

Comment: Could we also not simply do: `r = ResourceManager=std::move(ResourceManager(new_a));` and so it would not be necessary to implement an assignment operator at all?

Comment: On assignment. `b_ptr = std::move(that.b_ptr);` destroys what `b_ptr` points to, lets `b_ptr` point to what `that.b_ptr` points to and then empties `that.b_ptr` (sets the pointer to `nullptr`).

Comment: True `that` gets destroyed, but that is expected (I edited my answer to mention this.) but you still have `*this` pointing to a B and a C with the C pointing to the corresponding B.

Comment: I do, however, agree with your comment that having C point to B this way is dangerous.   `shared_ptr<B>` rather than `unique_ptr<B>` might be in order.

Comment: That was Matthieu's comment ;) -- anyway, the problem is not `that`, but `*this`. As long as `*(this->c_ptr)` contains a reference to `*(this->b_ptr)`, the former should be destroyed before the latter. So you should assign to those pointers in reverse order (first to `this->c_ptr`, then to `this->b_ptr`) so that the objects currently owned by `this->X_ptr` get destroyed in the right order. Or use move-and-swap :)

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer to reflect your and Matthieu's comments.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys! However, is there any reason why I cannot use `std::swap` directly rather than defining `swap` as you did above?

Comment: std::swap won't work because it requires copyable parameters.  The compiler won't generate a copy constructor for ResourceManager, and you can't write one yourself because that would require copying unique_ptrs  Try it.  It's a good idea to recognize the error messages that result since they are not obvious.

Comment: What if this and that are same one in `ResourceManager& operator=(ResourceManager&& that) `?