# Is it okay to throw exceptions from the constructor in this case?

Tags: java, exception, constructor

While working on a course (as in, school courses) database system for a school project, I stumbled upon an issue of debate.

I have a class called Course. Here is a constructor (the other one is a blank constructor that assigns default values) for the class:

```
public Course(String name, String code, char level, int academicYear)
{
    serialNumber = nextSerialNumber++;
    if (name == null) 
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("Name can not be null.");
    }
    else
    {
        this.name = name;
    }  
    if (code == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException("Code can not be null.");
    }
    else
    {
        this.code = code;
    }
    if (indexOf(level, VALID_LEVEL) == -1)
    {
        throw new InvalidLevelException("Level must be one of " 
            + "characters defined in the public array in Course.");
    }
    else
    {
        this.level = level;
    }
    if (String.valueOf(academicYear).length() != NUMBER_OF_DIGITS_IN_YEAR)
    {
        throw new InvalidYearException("Year must be a four digit number!");
    }
    else
    {
        this.academicYear = academicYear;
    }
}
```

Where

```
InvalidLevelException
```

and

```
InvalidYearException
```

are custom exceptions that are subclasses of

```
RuntimeException
```

I throw exceptions from that constructor to indicate if anything has gone wrong. For example, if, while reading from the data file, I encounter bad data, I can reject it and write it to a log (as the project mandates), simply by putting that constructor in a try-catch block and then catching those exceptions, and inside that catch block, log the bad data.

After showing this code to my teacher, he said it is inappropriate to throw exceptions from the constructor. However, I have read numerous Stackoverflow posts in which this practice is encouraged.

My question is: Is it okay to throw exceptions from the above constructor?

Reputable sources (for example, official documents or authoritative books) attached with an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: I think this is mostly opinion based.  I wouldn't directly throw a NullPointerException though.  I'd throw an IllegalArgumentException.  It might make sense to explicitly list what type of exceptions can be thrown though. Also javadoc it as to the exceptions and when they occur.  In general I try to avoid it, but I think this is a data validation so it should be fine.

Comment: Just look at the code of JDK `HashMap` class implementation. Check this constructor: `public HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)`, that contains: `if (initialCapacity < 0) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal initial capacity: " + initialCapacity); }`

Comment: You should ask why your instructor thinks that way. Maybe he might have some insight that the numerous authors don't. In any case, if you're not catching the errors in your constructor, you're going to have to catch them elsewhere, either when your object actually needs to operate on it (which can be a big waste of time and resources that could have been avoided early on), or you're going to have to hope everyone knows to check for those issues. Which is not guaranteed either.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810839/throwing-exceptions-from-constructors

Comment: For this case, you may use a `CourseBuilder` class that will take the necessary data to create a `Course` and throw the exceptions in the `build()` method, so the exceptions can be moved from `Course` constructor and be inside `build()` method. But this results in over complicating a simple and elegant design. You should tell your professor to pay a visit to this site, probably by posting a question :).

Comment: Closed?? Really?  I think this is totally valid. In fact, Google Guava has a great library for doing this: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong from throw an exception in the constructor. It means that the object can't be created in a valid state.

Personally you throw the right exception, but don't use custom exceptions if you can use Java exceptions `InvalidLevelException` and `InvalidYearException` should be replaced with `IllegalArgumentException` while `NullPointerException` is the right exception if an argument is null.

Another thing i would change is the style: Check your arguments **then** do everything else.

```
public Course(String name, String code, char level, int academicYear)
{
    if (name == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Name can not be null.");
    }
    if (code == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Code can not be null.");
    }

    if (indexOf(level, VALID_LEVEL) == -1) {
        throw new InvalidLevelException("Level must be one of " 
            + "characters defined in the public array in Course.");
    }

    if (String.valueOf(academicYear).length() != NUMBER_OF_DIGITS_IN_YEAR) {
        throw new InvalidYearException("Year must be a four digit number!");
    }

    serialNumber = nextSerialNumber++;
    this.code = code;
    this.academicYear = academicYear;
    this.level = level;
    this.name = name;
}
```

(p.s if the object can't be created, why increment serial number?)

It's very elegant right? -- Another thing is to make the messages more specific.

Anyway, i think the best source is the entire JDK platform since it's a common pattern to thrown an exception in the constructor.

---

As Luiggi Mendoza said in comments, it's [`HashMap` constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.%3Cinit%3E%28int,float%29) if you need a prof for your teacher

```
187     public More ...HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
188         if (initialCapacity < 0)
189             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal initial capacity: " +
190                                                initialCapacity);
191         if (initialCapacity > MAXIMUM_CAPACITY)
192             initialCapacity = MAXIMUM_CAPACITY;
193         if (loadFactor <= 0 || Float.isNaN(loadFactor))
194             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal load factor: " +
195                                                loadFactor);
196 
197         // Find a power of 2 >= initialCapacity
198         int capacity = 1;
199         while (capacity < initialCapacity)
200             capacity <<= 1;
201 
202         this.loadFactor = loadFactor;
203         threshold = (int)(capacity * loadFactor);
204         table = new Entry[capacity];
205         init();
206     }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it okay to throw exceptions from the above constructor?

Your question touches on one aspect of `Exception` handling. The other aspect is accurately describing the problem. I'll go through both briefly.

**Is the exception thrown where the code fails?**

The reasoning for this is simple. You want the user to know exactly where the problem occurred, and if you're propagating your exception all over the place, then you're going to make it more difficult for a user of your code to decipher where the issue is. If the issue is in the constructor of an object, you know the issue occurred during that object's creation.

That provides the user with an important clue, which is all you can do. You don't know how the user will *mis* use your code, so you need to make it as easy as possible for them to decipher the *source* of their issue.

**Does the exception message describe the problem?**

Using the appropriate type of `Exception` is important. If they've provided an invalid parameter, throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. If they have provided a null value, throw a `NullPointerException`. The `Exception` should be as effective as possible at describing the problem.

The second part of this is the message you attach. The amount of times I've seen:

```
Exception: Exception Occurred
```

is frustratingly high. It doesn't help in the slightest, and is an extremely lazy way of handling your code. You need to make it clear:

```
NullPointerException: Parameter X was null
```

Instantly, the user knows that the value they're passing for `X` is `null`. Simply put, make sure that the message specifically describes the issue that caused it.

**Extra Reading**

- For more details on this subject, check out [this link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/04/java-exception-handling-best-practices/) for the best practises on exception handling. This will help clear up any other questions you've got.