# c++ how to handle initializer that throws exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

Pretty simple question, how does one handle initializing a class member variable that possibly throws exceptions from it's constructor?

```
class main
{
public:
    main() c(...) {};
private:
    my_class c;
};

class my_class
{
public:
    inline my_class() : o(...) { };

private:
    some_obj o;
};
```

Clearly you can't try catch exceptions in a constructor initializer, so then would it be more appropriate instead to construct the object within a try catch block within the constructor?

This is a top-level class, so handling the exception to let a user know what happened and exiting gracefully is a priority over letting the program crash due to the exception?

```
class main
{
public:
    main()
    {
        try
        {
            c(...);
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            ...
        }
    };
private:
    my_class c;
};
```

However, this wouldn't work, because the object gets initialized once before it does within the constructor, and therefore the program may crash if the object throws an exception.

Comment: You can use a function-try-block with the constructor, to catch exceptions thrown during initialization of members. Note that the only sensible thing to do here is to re-throw an exception. In most cases it is poor design to allow the program to proceed with a partially-constructed object.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: A *function-try-block* on a constructor or destructor automatically re-throws at the end of the exception handler.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, I was not intending on continuing the program, rather attempting to perform a more graceful exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [function-try-block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block). It's designed specifically to address your issue.

```
class main
{
public:
    main() try : c(...)
    {
        std::cout << "constructed, c = " << c << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "failed to construct c = " << c << std::endl;
    } // implicit throw; here

private:
    my_class c;
};
```

Comment: Interesting, never seen this. Is this a c++11+ feature?
Are you allowed to use these with constructors?

Comment: No. It's a feature C++ has always had. And yes, it can be used with constructors.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera this exists *specifically because* a constructor's initializer list allows throw-able code outside of a function body.  This is what it's for.

Answer (score -1):

Why can you not catch the error in the constructor? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810839/throwing-exceptions-from-constructors?rq=1) it seems to be standard practice.

Comment: Because the object gets initialized before you initialize it within the constructor.

Comment: @FranciscoAguilera, The link includes function try block syntax.